# JavaFX Removing a single item from a ComboBox

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

So my code looks like this:

```
String name1 = "George";
String name2 = "Sally";
ComboBox<String> myCombo = new ComboBox();
myCombo.getItems().addAll(name1);
myCombo.getItems().addAll(name2);
```

I want to be able to remove Sally from the combo box after an event is called. I've tried searching for a simple solution and I've thought about
replacing the whole combo box with a new one, just without the last item.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

```
myCombo.getItems().remove(name2);
```

Comment: thanks!! would I be able to add an event listener to an item in the box? So when I click on it I can remove it?